# Output *.pdf file to a different directory using latexmk

Tags: pdf, latexmk, output, directory, visual-studio-code

I'm using `latexmk` in Visual Studio Code and I'd like to output the .pdf file to the current directory (same directory as the .tex file), while outputting all auxiliary files to a different directory.

I've tried messing with -outdir and -auxdir, but those options didn't seem to work.

First line of .log file: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.1.31)  12 FEB 2020 16:44`

Is this possible?

Comment: Which distribution of TeX are you using?  Setting -auxdir and -outdir to different values only works for MiKTeX, as is stated in the latexmk documentation. If instead you are using TeXLive, the auxdir has to be the same as outdir, because that is all the underlying programs support.

Comment: I think I'm using TeXLive, but where can I see which distribution I'm using?

Comment: Look at the the first line of the .log file generated by a run of pdflatex.

Comment: @JohnCollins I edited the post with that line, so as you can see I'm using TeXLive. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying (I've been out of electronic contact for a couple of weeks). Unfortunately, as stated in my first comment, since you are using TeXLive, having aux_dir and out_dir is not supported.  It would require some programming of latexmk itself to get around this limitation of the TeXLive implementation.

Comment: Which other distributions could I use that would make me able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem using TeXLive and found this [latexmkrc](https://github.com/debian-tex/latexmk/blob/upstream/4.65/example_rcfiles/fix-aux.latexmkrc) file.
Simply put the contents into a file named LatexMk (no file extension) in C:\latexmk if you're on Windows. Then you can use -auxdir with TexLive.

I couldn't find the mentioned file in the current distribution of latexmk, so it may be outdated or have some other bugs that I'm unaware of. However, it is running fine for me. (Windows 11, TexLive 2023)